# Can ReactJS and StoryBook use same scss file for same look and field

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I create Table Component and using Table.scss file for css. But It does not apply to StoryBook. This is my first time to use StoryBook. All the component's feature and functionality and doc are working as expected. But All css style are not woking in StoryBook. May I know how to add my Table.scss file into StoryBook.

Comment: Did you import `Table.scss` inside `Table.js`?

Comment: Hi @yousoumar, I change to styled-components and I used storybook-addon-styled-component-theme. Now It is ok now.